# Diagnosis PS2 laser issue

Tags: technical-issues, ps2

I own a  SCPH-39004 FAT PlayStation 2. It only reads one game (Gladiator), and for other games, shows a disk read error screen.

I tried to clean the lens, and adjust the lens height through two related screws. I also turned the lens potentiometeres clockwise a bit, but no luck.

*I don't have oscilloscope, but a HIOKI 3256 multimeter*.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: This seems to be an awful lot like a console version of lifehacks; "How do I fix this with these tools?" We might be able to help fix it, but I don't think listing tools helps, as it may take much more than just that.

Answer (score 3):

Disk Read Errors are very common on older PS2s, especially the "fat" models. By the sounds of it, replacing the full optical block would probably be your best option for a guaranteed fix. There are many on eBay in the ~$20 range. In my opinion, this would be a much easier fix than diagnosing the laser/other components.